# How to share functionality between controllers in Symfony when dealing with forms?

Tags: forms, symfony, view, controllers

Let's imagine that we want to build a simple cms application in Symfony, we are going to code the functionality to "crud" the posts and then we are going to display that data in a custom format using twig and css so it looks appealing to our users, obviously we have to make it easy to look for a specific post by adding search functionality.

So we create the search form by using a form class so we can reuse the form later:

```
<?php
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Post;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SearchType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class SearchForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('search_texfield', SearchType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Search ...',
            ),
            'label' => false,
        ))
        ->add('search_button', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Search',
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

The problem that i am facing is that i have to create the same form per controller, [home controller, results controller, some controller...], basically every view to which the user has access must have the search functionality or Symfony will launch $search_form is not defined basically because the header which contain the search form is shared to all the views as all of them extends base.layout.twig so the next block of code is repeated per view.

```
$search_form = $this->createForm(SearchForm::class);

return $this->render('some.view.twig', [
   'search_form' => $search_form->createView(),
   ...
]);
```

What could be an approach to share this form without having to define it per controller?

Comment: Do you want to search for the same thing on every page?  For example, each page allows a search for a post containing some text.

Comment: Take a look at [embedded controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before - Embedded controllers are one way to go. Just be careful to not use too many of them as they can be expensive.

Second option is defining service and including it as global to your templates (you stated you need it everywhere). How to do it is described
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.htm. This service then can create this form and provide it to template. With this approach you can have one service, which will provide form and second service which will provide setting filtering criteria (for example on Doctrine ORM).